# Won’t start with touching starter solenoid with screwdriver and it turns off my speedometer and glitches out!

Tags: transmission, manual-transmission

I’ve been having problems with my 09 Kawasaki Ex250R. Every time I go to click ignition switch I hear a click in the electrical relay near battery. It might be that but I also tried bypassing the starter solenoid and it just shuts my bike off and restarts my speedometer. I’m thinking it might be battery’s but I’m confused cause it reads 9.17 but seems to be dead too. I need help. I’m trying to rule out problems but I keep hitting a wall. Please help. I’ve already tried bypassing the solenoid doesn’t do anything but restart my bike and I ordered a new electrical relay cause that’s were I here the click every time I press ignition. Might be the relay, battery, or something else.

Comment: The battery is supposed to read +12V, sounds like dead battery to me. You might have bought an unnecessary new relay.. At least they are not that expensive. You can take your battery to a shop and try to get it charged, if it can still hold charge for at least a short time you can test it and confirm if it's the battery or not.

Comment: I appreciate it man! How much does it cost for them to charge it?

Comment: Replace the battery with anew one.

Comment: About $150.  And it'll look like a new battery when they're done! :)

Answer (score 2):

9V is still enough to operate the relay, but not enough to operate the starter. It's not just a matter of voltage but the internal resistance of the battery, which if high enough will just bring the terminal voltage down to the point that nothing, including the speedo and ignition, will work.

A good 12V battery will not fall below about 11.5V even when near fully discharged, and 9V sounds like one of the cells within the battery has failed - there are 6 cells of 2V each that make up the battery. Maybe one or more of the plates has separated, or it has lost the electrolyte, or is just sulphated up. This would certainly cause the internal resistance to be too high to be usable.

You can get it charged (or buy yourself a charger, which you should have if the bike is ever standing for any length of time) but I doubt that it will recover, so plan on a new battery.